# Lie algebra of an algebraic group generated by connected subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let V be a vector space over an algebraically closed field.

Let $\{H_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of closed connected subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ (wrt. Zariski topology). It is a basic result in algebraic groups that the subgroup $G$ generated by the $H_i$ is a closed connected subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(V)$. In fact, we have $G = H_{i_1} \cdots H_{i_n}$ for some $i_1, \ldots i_n \in I$. (For example 7.5 "Linear Algebraic Groups" by Humphreys).

Is the Lie algebra of $G$ generated by the Lie algebras of the $H_i$?

Comment: I'd guess we could have counterexamples in positive characteristic, namely with $G$ unipotent, connected, non-abelian, with abelian Lie algebra.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, maybe I should have mentioned that counterexamples could only be found in positive characteristic. In characteristic zero the answer is positive, or more generally when the product map $H_{i_1} \times \cdots \times H_{i_t} \rightarrow G$ is separable.

Comment: Hence, what is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p=\mathrm{char}(k)>0$. The vector group $G=\mathbf{G}_a^2$ is generated by $H_1=\{(t,0)|t\in k\}$ and $H_2=\{(t,t^p)\mid t\in k\}$ but $\mathrm{Lie}H_1=\mathrm{Lie}H_2=k\oplus 0$.